# Unable to run ./program with exec and makeargv in c

Tags: c, unix, exec, argv

So to start off, this program has two main parts. The first takes input from the command line using fgets and then makes an argv array with a function called makeargv. The second, takes that argv array and runs it using execvp. The problem I am having is that the program will only run system programs such as "ls", "pwd", "vim", etc. but will not run any program when the directory is specified, such as "./program". I have already tried different versions of exec but the only difference that has made is that then my program will no longer run any commands.

For the below program I cut out all the code that was not relevant to the question to avoid confusion.

```
#ifndef MAX_CANON
#define MAX_CANON 8192
#endif

int makeargv(const char *s, const char *delimiters, char ***argvp);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
char cmd[MAX_CANON];
char delim[] = "\t";
char **myargv;



printf("Beginning program...\nEnter a command to execute:\n");
while(fgets(cmd, MAX_CANON, stdin) != NULL){    // Here's where I get input from the command line
    /* Remove newline from end of command */
    if (*(cmd + strlen(cmd) - 1) == '\n' || *(cmd + strlen(cmd) - 1) == ' ' )
        *(cmd + strlen(cmd) - 1) = 0;

    /*---- Child Code ----*/
    if((p = fork()) == 0){  
        if (makeargv(cmd, delim, &myargv) == -1) {  // Here is where I make the argv array
            fprintf(stderr, "Child failed to construct an argument array for %s\n", &cmd[0]);
            return 1;
        }

      fprintf(stderr, "Command is: %s\n", *&myargv[0]); 
        if(execvp(myargv[0], &myargv[0]) == -1){   // Here is where the error keeps appearing
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to execute command!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } 
    /*---- Parent Code ----*/
```

Here is the makeargv code

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int makeargv(const char *s, const char *delimiters, char ***argvp) {
   int error;
   int i;
   int numtokens;
   const char *snew;
   char *t;

   if ((s == NULL) || (delimiters == NULL) || (argvp == NULL)) {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return -1;
   }
   *argvp = NULL;                           
   snew = s + strspn(s, delimiters);         /* snew is real start of string */
   if ((t = malloc(strlen(snew) + 1)) == NULL) 
      return -1; 
   strcpy(t, snew);               
   numtokens = 0;
   if (strtok(t, delimiters) != NULL)     /* count the number of tokens in s */
      for (numtokens = 1; strtok(NULL, delimiters) != NULL; numtokens++) ; 

                             /* create argument array for ptrs to the tokens */
   if ((*argvp = malloc((numtokens + 1)*sizeof(char *))) == NULL) {
      error = errno;
      free(t);
      errno = error;
      return -1; 
   } 
                        /* insert pointers to tokens into the argument array */
   if (numtokens == 0) 
      free(t);
   else {
      strcpy(t, snew);
      **argvp = strtok(t, delimiters);
      for (i = 1; i < numtokens; i++)
          *((*argvp) + i) = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    } 
    *((*argvp) + numtokens) = NULL;             /* put in final NULL pointer */
    return numtokens;
}
```

Edit:

Swapped fprintf for perror.

```
if(execvp(myargv[0], &myargv[0]) == -1){   // Here is where the error keeps appearing
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to execute command!\n");
    return 1;
}

if(execvp(myargv[0], &myargv[0]) == -1){   // Here is where the error keeps appearing
    perror("Error: Failed to execute command!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I am now getting a "No such file or directory" error.

FIXED:
The `makeargv` program was using `"\t"` as it's delimeter instead of `" "` so it was not creating the array correctly.

Changing:

```
char delim[] = "\t";
```

To:

```
char delim[] = " ";
```

Fixes the problem.

Comment: How are the following variables defined in your first source: cmd, myargv, and delim?

Comment: I added them to my original post at the top of the program.

Comment: Your code works in my system with a local copy of /bin/ls to the current directory... Can you confirm your "./program" is an ELF executable file (and not an executable script, that requires an interpreter)?

Comment: It is. It is another C program compiled with gcc.

Comment: The code shown misses to prototype `fork()` and `execvp()`. Also `p` is undefined.

Comment: `*&` is either a compile-time error or no-op.

Comment: Also, you'll want to find out *what* error occurred - print the message with `perror("Error: Failed to execute command")` instead!

Comment: @alk Thank you but as mentioned in my initial question, this is only a small part of the whole program, which runs successfully except for execvp and makeargv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 type of exec:

- the first need a path as the environment PATH who contain a location (where find sys executables)
- and the others how take real file location.

> Form the man page (https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec):
>
> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified filename does not **contain a slash (/) character**.

So this mean that you need to use an absolute location, who always begin with /.

You can use getwd() and strcat() to concatenate the 2 strings.

For execvp:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]); // From the man (I <3 mans)
```

So:

```
char argv[3][] = { "/bin/ls", "/", NULL};
if (execvp("/bin/ls", argv) == -1)
      return (1);
```

For evecv:

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

There is a problem, it need the system PATH. If you don't know what it is type "echo $PATH" in bash. It's a list of directories where the system can find binaries like "ls" in "/bin", concatenate with ":" as sparator. I find the exact definition [here](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

For your makeargv:

I don't understand why you deference it and take the address after.

> execvp(myargv[0], &myargv[0])

```
char **myargv; //That's we have 
char *const argv[]; //that's we need

//so you should try simply:
execvp(myargv[0], myargv);
//or if there is a cast problem
execvp(myargv[0], (char *const[])myargv);
```

Good luck!

Comment: So I have read the man pages and tried system commands, absolute paths, and relative paths with both `execvp()` and `execv()`. The first works with system command but that's it while the second doesn't work for anything I have passed it. Do you know if the path to the executable needs to be given a certain way? For example I've been giving the path to my program as `/home/user/folder/.../myprogram arg1 arg2` which is what `pwd` returns in the console.

Comment: Thanks for trying but while that does work, it’s not exactly what I’m trying to figure out. My makeargv program works already and constructs an argv array to be passed to exec so what I’m trying to figure out is why the array created but makeargv doesn’t work for any version of exec as long as the program to be run is in the current directory or not specified in my PATH.

Comment: Ok, I think found a problem, look at the post :)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, program won't compile. While it is the right type for `execvp`, `makeargv` won't accept it.

Comment: Fixed the problem! I was using `"\t"` as my delimiter `in makeargv` instead of `" "` so my whole program and it's arguments were the first index of my array. The whole program works now as expected. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The cast here  `execvp(myargv[0], (char *const[])myargv);` is useless.